# On macOS, how can I identify the app or process that captures a particular keyboard shortcut?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I use an app in which <kbd>Ctrl+1</kbd> is supposed to do something. But it doesn't do anything.

I created a [testbed on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z7ajfp1e/1/) and <kbd>Ctrl+1</kbd> is not captured there either.

I checked the OS' keyboard settings and, as you can see here, <kbd>Ctrl+1</kbd> is not hooked up there.

[image: macOS keyboard preferences]

I can't figure out what's using it. Is there some tool or place where I can see where a keyboard shortcut is routed?

Comment: idk your solution, unfortunately - however, one further thing you will have to chase through... if you have a keyboard with a 10-key, the 10-key 1 is not recognised the same as the 'qwerty' 1. The control panel doesn't show the differentiation, but the OS recognises them as different, so you can actually use both to perform different keyed functions. Your testbed recognises my ctrl [qwerty] 1, but not ctrl [10key] 1. *(edit)* ah, yes it does if I switch off the mission control keys, but it can't tell me which is which like the OS can.

Comment: [Key Codes](https://manytricks.com/keycodes/) can tell the difference - https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eO9I.png

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks for the idea! The 10-key thing doesn't seem to be the problem though. Here Ctrl-2 works but Ctrl-1 doesn't.